# express-gateway- is that possible to save response result to database?

Tags: mongodb, express, microservices, api-gateway, express-gateway

i have a question about express-gateway

i did routing in express gateway and when i hit use postman i got following response

```
{
"response": {
    "rescode": "0",
    "hp": "0822xxxx",
    "vtype": "ADB",
    "server_trxid": "8811",
    "partner_trxid": "ADB20181005041237",
    "scrmessage": "DALAM PROSES",
    "resmessage": "Status order ADBPJS20181005041237 adalah Dalam Proses"
} }
```

the question is, is possible to store that response to MongoDB or mySQL?
if its possible, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

this is a little odd question; I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Right now Express Gateway does not offer any hook possibility for the response which means — once the response comes to the gateway it gets simply forwarded back to the original client.

You can hook into this using a plugin though; in that case you can manipulate the response; among the possibilities, you can save the response in a database, for sure.

What's the reason for this? In case you're trying to cache the response for a later reuse (that's the only thing that comes in my mind right now) you might want to use a different mechanism.

Cheers,

V.